# Quicksort linear time?

Tags: c++, performance, quicksort, qsort

I'm doing an analysis for the quicksort (qsort from c++ STL) algorithm, the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

#define MIN_ARRAY 256000
#define MAX_ARRAY 1000000000
#define MAX_RUNS 100

using namespace std;

int* random_array(int size) {
    int* array = new int[size];

    for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
        array[c] = rand()*rand() % 1000000;
    }

    return array;
}

int compare(const void* a, const void* b) { 
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b); 
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("data.csv");
    fout << "array size,";
    srand(time(NULL));
    int size;
    int counter = 1;

    std::clock_t start;
    double duration;

    for (size = MIN_ARRAY; size < MAX_ARRAY; size *= 2) {
        fout << size << ",";
    }
    fout << "\n";

    for (counter = 1; counter <= MAX_RUNS; counter++) {
        fout << "run " << counter << ",";
        for (size = MIN_ARRAY; size < MAX_ARRAY; size *= 2) {
            try {
                int* arr = random_array(size);

                start = std::clock();
                qsort(arr, size, sizeof(int), compare);
                duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

                //cout << "size: " << size << " duration: " << duration << '\n';
                fout << setprecision(15) << duration << ",";

                delete[] arr;
            }
            catch (bad_alloc) {
                cout << "bad alloc caught, size: " << size << "\n";
                fout << "bad alloc,";
            }

        }
        fout << "\n";
        cout << counter << "% done\n";
    }
    
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

when I run this, the data comes back perfectly linear:

[image: data]

what on earth is going on? Isnt quicksort O(nlogn)?

Here's the array sizes used and the average time in seconds for each size for all 100 runs:

```
arraysize,256000,512000,1024000,2048000,4096000,8192000,16384000,32768000,65536000,131072000,262144000,524288000
average,0.034,0.066,0.132,0.266,0.534,1.048,2.047,4.023,7.951,15.833,31.442
```

Comment: I feel like `rand() * rand()` overflows all over the place.

Comment: Do note that `rand()*rand()` can easily lead to undefined behavior for signed integer overflow.

Comment: Your compare function also looks broken.  Why are you using `return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b); ` instead of `return (*(int*)a < *(int*)b); `?

Comment: thanks for the help everyone! on my machine, rand_max is only like 31000 or so, so rand()*rand() shouldnt overflow.  for the compare function, i took that from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/.  And its just for a school project, and i thought qsort would be easier to analyze.  thanks again everyone!

Comment: Just an observation but having only 10^6 possible random numbers but sets that are orders of magnitude greater means that there will be a lot of grouped numbers that are the same. This will affect your speed tests by significant amounts in addition to the problem that NLog(N) wiil become more asymptotic as N grows.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Actually, the comparison function of qsort is supposed to work the way the OP did it. Yeah, kind of odd but a holdover from C

Answer (score 4):

It is, on average, indeed  *O(N log N)*.

It's just that a graph of *f(N) = N log(N)* appears remarkably linear.

Graph it and see for yourself, or refer to the one below. This average time is what makes the algorithm so very clever:

[image]

Comment: Notably, in the OP's graph, it basically goes from x=5m to x=30m. And `lg2(5m)=22.25`, and `lg2(30m)=24.8`, so the graph looks remarkably similar to the linear equation `y=23.5x`

Comment: Yup. And thanks for the edit ;-). The key thing for me is that df / dN is 1 + log N. In other words, the gradient is practically constant.

Comment: Your example graph might be more obvious if you used a larger range of maximum X, and then made the blue line y=10X instead of y=x.

Comment: Actually, the times are nearly linear, not NLogN, because of the clustering of duplicates from the limited number of random ints in [0:1,000,000).

Comment: @doug: We will have to agree to disagree. Never mind about the sampling. The fact remains that I think most folk don't realise how straight the N log(N) plot is - rather they expect it to be 1/2 way between N and N ** 2.

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't think we even disagree as people that aren't familiar with qsort's algorithm's gentle slope from the LogN and aren't aware how close it is to just being linear. My point is that the OP's results are much closer to being exactly linear due to the limited random number set he chose. It pretty much obliterates the LogN factor. While small, it is visible with a large random number set..

Answer (score 3):

The reason the slope looks linear is partly the slow change in Log(N) but the main reason is that the random numbers that populate the array are limited to [0-1,000,000). This causes the large arrays to mostly be filled with duplicates and as the qsort algorithm gets down to smaller groups, sorting becomes much faster. As the array size increases from, say 10,000,000 to 20,000,000 the duplicates double in count on average and hence the sorting tracks almost entirely linearly.

This can be seen from the following graph:

[image: Sort time of unconstrained and constrained int arrays]

The orange and grey lines are the execution times of the unconstrained and constrained  arrays. The yellow and blue lines are linear from 0 to the end points of two runs. One run has ints constrained to [0-1000000) from the original code. The other isunconstrained to the 2^31 positive ints. Note how much longer the unconstrained sort takes since sorting of the increasing groups of duplicates is extremely fast.

Here's the code modification that shows the unconstrained execution time has a distinct curve as one would expect from NLogN.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

#define MIN_ARRAY 256000
#define MAX_ARRAY 1000000000
#define MAX_RUNS 100

using namespace std;

int* random_array(int size) {
    int* array = new int[size];

    for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
        // array[c] = rand() * rand() % 1000000;
            // Note that as the array size grows beyond 1000000
            // this will produce increasing numbers of duplicates
            // which will shorten the time when the subsets get small
    
        array[c] = (rand() << 16) | (rand() << 1) | (rand() & 1);
            // Note that in this example/system, RAND_MAX==0x7fff
            // get a random positive int distributed in the set of positive, 32 bit ints
    }

    return array;
}

int compare(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

int main()
{
    auto x = RAND_MAX;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("data.csv");
    fout << "array size,";
    srand(time(NULL));
    int size;
    int counter = 1;

    std::clock_t start;
    double duration;

    for (size = MIN_ARRAY; size < MAX_ARRAY; size *= 2) {
        fout << size << ",";
    }
    fout << "\n";

    for (counter = 1; counter <= MAX_RUNS; counter++) {
        fout << "run " << counter << ",";
        for (size = MIN_ARRAY; size < MAX_ARRAY; size *= 2) {
            try {
                int* arr = random_array(size);

                start = std::clock();
                qsort(arr, size, sizeof(int), compare);
                duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

                cout << "size: " << size << " duration: " << duration << '\n';
                fout << setprecision(15) << duration << ",";

                delete[] arr;
            }
            catch (bad_alloc) {
                cout << "bad alloc caught, size: " << size << "\n";
                fout << "bad alloc,";
            }

        }
        fout << "\n";
        cout << counter << "% done\n";
    }

    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a nice analysis. Have a "you're late to the party but this is the better answer" upvote.